# Date stored as INT but formated as YYYYMMDD trying to convert to date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert a date stored as an integer in SQL but the format of it is `YYYYMMDD` so when I try to convert it or cast it as datetime it gives an overflow arithmetic error.

Examples

```
Select
Cast(DateExpire as Datetime)
Convert(dateime, DateExpire)
```

Comment: SELECT CAST('20201220' AS DATE)  works fine for me

Comment: Please provide your examples you have tried (with data examples)

Comment: SELECT CAST(CAST(20201220 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATE)

Comment: Correct, my fault, but this is why posting what you have tried first helps.

Comment: Select try_convert(date,left(20201221,8))

Comment: This is why you should use the appropriate datatype to store accurate and correct information. You obviously have numeric values that do not represent actual dates. Could be extra numerals at the end, extra zero-padding, invalid month values, invalid day values for month/year, etc. Learn this lesson well.

Comment: @SMor Have you ever done ETL or worked with importing data from sources you have no control over? You are making assumptions about them and their data. For all you know, this data is coming from an external source and they are trying to clean it up before inserting it into their database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), 20201221), 112)
```

Explanation:

First you'll want to convert it to a string:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), 20201221)
```

Then you want to convert that string, into a date. The date format you're storing it as, is `112` ([see documentation here for other types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles))

So you can convert it by saying "convert this string into a date, here's a hint as to the format this date string is formatted so you know how to convert it into a date"

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, 'yyyyMMdd', 112)
```

---

#### EDIT:

In the comments you mentioned this was throwing errors for you, and it seems you have some inconsistent data. You wanted to be able to exclude conversions that would otherwise throw an error. This was my recommendation:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), 20201221), 112) --Returns date
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), 20190229), 112) --Returns NULL, 2019 wasn't a leap year
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), 0), 112) --Returns NULL
```

`TRY_CONVERT()` is great for scenarios like this. You're able to convert all the values that are able to be converted, but you don't have a bunch of errors being thrown.

That said, it's good to see WHY those failed to convert. Perhaps you have some values that could be easily cleaned up first prior to being converted.

Comment: I just tried that but it gave me the error "conversion failed when converting date and or/time from character string" However it did look like it was going to work for a second before it put the error up

Comment: The syntax I've provided is correct. The problem is likely your data. You could have something like `20190229` in your data and it's failing because that date doesn't exist for 2019, because it's not a leap year. Try running `SELECT YourNumericDateField FROM YourTable WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), YourNumericDateField), 112) IS NULL` And that will tell you which dates are failing to convert. And I'd bet it's bad data.

Comment: edit I was able to exclude them from the search and it worked thank you! I did that it and gave me a long list is there a way to exclude those dates in the conversion?

Comment: This will only return the conversion if it was successful, otherwise it returns NULL: `TRY_CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), YourNumericDateField), 112)`, I would examine your data to see if there are ways to clean it up prior to running this conversion. Like maybe you need to use `varchar(20)` instead and take a `LEFT(X, 8)`. There's always more than one way to bake a cake, and I'm not aware of all your business requirements.